# Como utilizar a função range do Python neste caso em específico?

Tags: python, lógica

Eu tenho um problema e estou a procura da melhor maneira de resolver.

Eu tenho uma função que insere em um array 26 posições começando da letra **'a'** até a última letra do alfabeto que é a letra **'z'** : Ex:

```py
import random

def caractere_array():

    caractere = []
    for i in range(26):
        caractere.append(chr(65+i)) 


def novocaractere_array():

novocaractere = [65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65 ]
incluir = random.randrange(0,200)

for i in [chr(65+i)]: 
#valores a colocar o mesmo incluir 
    try:
        novocaractere[novocaractere.index(i)] = incluir 
    except:
        pass
```

> Achei que isso faria **'a'** n vezes

Gostaria de repetir o caractere **'a'** 26 vezes utilizando o **recurso range do Python**. Alguma ideia de como fazer algo parecido?

Comment: Se a lista deve conter apenas a letra `a`, por que fez `chr(65+i)`?

Comment: Uai isso não iria fazer a até n? Exemplo, a, a, a ... sendo char(65 até n vezes)?

Comment: Você sabe o que a função `chr` faz?

Comment: A função chr() devolve o caracter corresponde ao código numérico passado como parâmetro.

Comment: Tome cuidado ao editar a pergunta. Uma edição serve apenas para corrigir problemas presentes na pergunta ou melhorá-la, nunca para alterá-la e fazer novas perguntas. Se tem alguma dúvida que não foi abordada na pergunta original você deve criar uma nova.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def caractere_array():
    caractere = []
    for i in range(26):
        caractere.append(chr(65+i))
```

Você cria uma lista varia, define um laço de repetição que fará `i` variar de 0 a 25, inclusive, adicionado na lista o valor `chr(65+i)`.

Se a ideia é gerar uma lista apenas com a letra `'a'`, não faz sentido algum utilizar `chr(65+i)`, que gerará um caractere com base no valor de `i`: `'a'`, `'b'`, etc. Se a ideia é ter um mesmo valor, não tem porque variá-lo. No caso seria:

```py
def caractere_array():
    caractere = []
    for i in range(26):
        caractere.append('a')
```

Mas também não há porque fazer isso. Para gerar uma lista com 26 `'a'`, basta fazer:

```
caractere = ['a'] * 26
```